# Ms Access password Storage

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am using MS Access as a database for a school project. The following is my query:

```
public static string qry4 = "update INTERNETSETTINGS set password =  @password , url = @url , databasename = @databasename , port = @port , username = @username";
```

It is giving me the following error: `Syntax Error in Update Statement`

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", urlBox.Text.ToString());
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@databasename", databaseBox.Text.ToString());
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", portBox.Text.ToString());
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userBox.Text.ToString());
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text.ToString());
```

It is making me angry because every thing is ok and right on target but still I am getting the error, but when I remove password from query it works fine. Please Help.

Comment: If you have put the parameters in the correct order, please post the correct example, to avoid people wasting their time.

Comment: There was no problem in parameters, its still out of order but the error was because of the below post.

Comment: Run the query with the parameters in that order and @url will be written to password.

Comment: Thank you. I got ur point too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `password` is a reserved keyword.  Place it in braces...

```
update INTERNETSETTINGS set [password] = @password...
```

Comment: I cant vote u up :) but the answer is great , its what the error is because. Problem Solved.

Comment: It should still let you accept the answer.  :)  Glad it worked.

Comment: The downvote wasn't me.  Some other reserved words for Access for future reference - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266